# rails5, puma, nginxで繋げる事ができない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

初めまして。
かなり強引な書き方ですが、ruby on rails のアプリを公開したいと
思っています。

puma と nginxでしたいと思っています。参考になるようなサイトを
探して真似てみたのですがどうしてもつながりません。
どなたかエラーとなりそうな所を指摘もらえたらと願っています。

ちなみに下記でのpumaだけでは外部から見れます。。

```
rails  s -d -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

もちろんこの前に必要事項は`export`と`rails assets:precompile`は実行
しています。

私のhostの環境は次の通りです。

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 5.0.1

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

一部設定状況は下記の通りです。

```
******@nahs:~$ cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/app_nagao_2.conf
upstream app_nagao2 {
        server unix:/home/nagao/run/app_nagao2.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

server {
    listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.210.150;

    root /home/******/run/app_nagao2/public; # アプリケーション名を記述

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_nagao2; # アプリケーション名を記述

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://app_nagao2; # アプリケーション名を記述

app_nagao2/config/puma.rb
_proj_path = "#{File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)}"
_proj_name = File.basename(_proj_path)
_home = ENV.fetch("HOME") { "/home/******" }

pidfile "#{_home}/run/#{_proj_name}.pid"
bind "unix://#{_home}/run/#{_proj_name}.sock"
directory _proj_path


threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 8 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
```

ラン内での http://192.168.210.150:80 では正常に表示します。
でも外からのアクセスでは Welcome to Nginx だけで
私のページは表示されません。

/var/log/nginx/error.log に下記のようなメッセージが出ています。

```
www-data

[error] 1283#1283: *32 connect() to unix:/home/******/run/app_nagao2.sock failed (111: Connection refused)

root@nahs:~# ls -l /home/******/run/
合計 4
drwxrwxr-x 12 ****** ****** 4096  4月  1 22:29 app_nagao2
srwxrwxrwx  1 ****** ******   0  4月  3 20:16 app_nagao2.sock

cat /etc/group
　　・
　　・
******:x:1000:www-data
```

*****はサーバーでのログイン名です。
正直多くのところで内容が理解できていません。
何かアドバイスいただけたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考になさったサイトのURLを追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 参考にしたURLですが、

http://qiita.com/wordijp/items/32afa58238f5f83059a6
http://arakaji.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/03/200502
http://www.gakusmemo.com/?p=608
等です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくデフォルトの`server`ディレクティブが邪魔をしているのでしょう。

複数のホストが同一ポートに登録されている場合、Nginxは`Host`ヘッダと`server_name`ディレクティブを参照して利用するものを選択します。

もし単一アプリのみにそのサーバーを利用する予定ならばデフォルトのserverディレクティブ(おそらくnginx.confに定義されている)を削除orコメントアウトすればすべてのリクエストはそのアプリケーションに到達できるでしょう。

Comment: 返答有難うございます。
もし、言われた事を理解していませんでしたらすみません。
nginxをインストールした直後には/etc/nginx/conf.d/
ディレクトリーは空でした。現在は

root@nahs:~# ls -la /etc/nginx/conf.d/
合計 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  4月  1 17:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096  4月  1 17:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  795  4月  2 22:22 app_nagao2.conf
root@nahs:~#
となっています。その上のディレクトリー(nginx)に
nginx.confがあります。

Comment: 今、気がついたのですが、/etc/nginx/nginx.confの中に

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
の項目があります。/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
の中にリンクファイルがあり

listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
の様な記述があります。

Comment: ありがとうございました。　　include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

Comment: 上記をコメントアウトするとつながるようです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: Ubuntuだとそちらにデフォルトがありましたね、失礼しました。解決できたようでなによりです